# Why am I obtaining "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/fire/firestore/firestore' " error message in my Angular app?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angular-module

I am pretty new with Angular and Firebase\FireStore and I am finding the following difficulties trying to add Firestore connection to my project.

I was following the official documentation to add it to my specific project: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md

So, first of all, I installed AngularFire via NPM in my project by:

```
npm install --save firebase @angular/fire
```

Then I have done:

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

Then I configured my **/src/environments/environment.ts** file, in this way:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "MY-API-KEY",
    authDomain: "soc-dashboard.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://soc-dashboard.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "soc-dashboard",
    storageBucket: "soc-dashboard.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "801320773797"
    //appId: "1:801320773797:web:14e69306da7b0838d4c54c",
    //measurementId: "G-BHVTXG6CY4"
  }
};
```

Then I configured my **/src/app/app.module.ts** file in this way:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';    
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FullCalendarModule } from 'primeng/fullcalendar';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
import { FullcalendarComponent } from './fullcalendar/fullcalendar.component';
import { EventService } from './event.service';
import { PeopleListComponent } from './people-list/people-list.component';  
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DropdownModule, OrderListModule, CalendarModule, ConfirmDialog, ConfirmDialogModule, ConfirmationService } from 'primeng';
import {SelectButtonModule} from 'primeng/selectbutton';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CustomEventDateSelectorComponent } from './custom-event-date-selector/custom-event-date-selector.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import {AngularFireAuthModule} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {AngularFirestoreModule} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
  
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FullcalendarComponent,
    PeopleListComponent,
    CustomEventDateSelectorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    DropdownModule,
    OrderListModule,
    SelectButtonModule,
    CalendarModule,
    ConfirmDialogModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FullCalendarModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,

    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  providers: [EventService, ConfirmationService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

As you can see I configured the **AngularFireModule** by:

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
```

that should use the **environment.firebase** section defined into my **/src/environments/environment.ts** file.

Finnally in my project I have this **EventService** service class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore/firestore';


@Injectable()
export class EventService {

  //private events = [];

  private events = [
    {id: 1, title: 'All Day Event', start: '2017-02-01'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Long Event', start: '2017-02-07', end: '2017-02-10'},
    {id: 3, title: 'Repeating Event', start: '2017-02-09T16:00:00'},
    {id: 3, title: 'test', start: '2017-02-20T07:00:00'},
  ];


  private people = [
    {id: 1, name: "PERSONA 1"},
    {id: 2, name: "PERSONA 2"},
    {id: 3, name: "PERSONA 3"},
    {id: 4, name: "PERSONA 4"},
    {id: 5, name: "PERSONA 5"},
  ];

  items: Observable<any[]>;

  public eventData = new BehaviorSubject(this.events);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private db: AngularFirestore) {}

  getEvents(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.eventData.asObservable();
  }

  getItems(): Observable<any[]> {
    this.items = this.db.collection('calendar').valueChanges();

    return this.items;
  }


  addEvent(event) {
    console.log(event.event.end);
    const newEvent = {id: 5, title: event.event.title, start: event.event.start, end: event.event.end};
    event.event.remove();
    this.events.push(newEvent);
    this.eventData.next([...this.events]);
  }

  removeEventById(event:any): Observable<any[]>  {
    this.events=this.events.filter(each=>each.id!=event.id);
    console.log("EVENTS: " + this.events);
    //event.remove();
    let eventData = new BehaviorSubject(this.events);
    this.eventData.next(this.events);
    return this.eventData.asObservable();
  }


  getPeople(): Promise<any[]> {
    return Promise.all(this.people)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          return res;
        })
  }

}
```

As you can see in this class I am injecting the **AngularFirestore** into my constructor:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient,
            private db: AngularFirestore) {}
```

and then I am trying to use it to retrieve data from my **FireStore** database in this method:

```
getItems(): Observable<any[]> {
    this.items = this.db.collection('calendar').valueChanges();
    return this.items;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to execute my project by **ng serve** command I am obtaining the following error message:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/event.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/fire/firestore/firestore' in '/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/SOC-Calendar/src/app'
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

And I can't understand why.

This is my **package.json** file content:

```
{
  "name": "soc-calendar",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.4",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "firebase": "^7.15.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "primeicons": "^3.0.0-rc.1",
    "primeng": "^9.0.6",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": ">= 0.900 < 0.1100",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.0.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "open": "^7.0.3"
  }
}
```

I have worked on a previous Angular project using AngularFire. This project works fine and was downloaded from a Udemy course and it seems to me that this working fine coure uses an oldest version of **@angular/fire"** (the **^5.2.1** instead the **^6.0.2** that I am currentrly using in my project).

Als the **node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/** content of the old working project seems pretty different from my actual project giving me this problem. Infact:

This is the directory content of the old working project:

[image]

And this is the content of the same directory in my new problematic project:

[image]

As you can see the old working project contains more file respect the new one, including the **firestore.js** and the **firestore.module.js** file that are not present in my new project.

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please paste only the relevant code, not your entire project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore/firestore';
```

While in the official docs the import statement is

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

(As per link you yourself provided).

Answer (score 0):

the reason is; in your package.json, you have Angular v9, which does not support AngularFireModule. The best way is copy the angular dependencies to below and it will work

```
    {
  "name": "old",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.21.5",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.21.5",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.21.5",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.21.5",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-audio": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.21.6",
    "@ionic-native/printer": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": "^3.0.9",
    "cordova-plugin-printer": "^0.8.0",
    "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-res": "^0.9.0",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^5.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "7.14.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.10.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.10.12",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "28.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION": "16.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-printer": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "28.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```